# How to save an input value in a JSON object using pure javascript and then save it in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I think that the title explains itself. I need to save the input values in a object and then save this object in a array.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Teste</title>
  </head>
  <script>
    function vai(){
      var pessoa = {
      nome = document.getElementById('nome').value,
      idade = document.getElementById('idade').value
    };
      var i = 0;
      var pessoas = [];
      pessoas[i] = pessoa{};
      i++;
    }

  </script>

  <body>
    <label>Digite seu nome aqui</label>
    <input type='text' id='nome' placeholder='aquii'>
    <label>Digite sua idade aqui</label>
    <input type='text' id='idade' placeholder='aquii'>
    <button onclick='vai()'>
      Teste aqui
    </button>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix three things:

- Use `:` inside Object literals `{}` instead of `=`
- Declare the main array `pessoas` in the global scope so it don't get change on every click
- Use `push()` to add the object at the end of array.

Below is the working snippet.

```js
var pessoas = [];

function vai() {
  var pessoa = {
    nome: document.getElementById('nome').value,
    idade: document.getElementById('idade').value
  };
  pessoas.push(pessoa)
  console.log(pessoas)
}
```

```html
<label>Digite seu nome aqui</label>
    <input type='text' id='nome' placeholder='aquii'>
    <label>Digite sua idade aqui</label>
    <input type='text' id='idade' placeholder='aquii'>
    <button onclick='vai()'>
      Teste aqui
    </button>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didin't know the push() function. But just one more question, what if I wanted to save without push? Would this be possible?

Comment: @aquasp You can use length of the array `pessoas[pessoas.length] = pessoa`

Answer (score 3):

You should declare the array in the global environment (outside the function). You also have some syntax issue inside the object (should be `:` instead of `=`). Then you can simply [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the object into the array in each button click.

Try the following way:

```js
var pessoas = [];
function vai(){
  var pessoa = {
    nome: document.getElementById('nome').value,
    idade: document.getElementById('idade').value
  };
  pessoas.push(pessoa);
  console.log(pessoas);
}
```

```html
<label>Digite seu nome aqui</label>
<input type='text' id='nome' placeholder='aquii'>
<label>Digite sua idade aqui</label>
<input type='text' id='idade' placeholder='aquii'>
<button onclick='vai()'>
  Teste aqui
</button>
```

You approach without using the `push()` by maintaining a variable is almost correct except the variable declaration scope. You have to declare that as a global variable. You can assign the object into the current position and increment that in each function call:

```js
var pessoas = [];
var i = 0;
function vai(){
  var pessoa = {
    nome: document.getElementById('nome').value,
    idade: document.getElementById('idade').value
  };
  pessoas[i] = pessoa;
  i++;
  console.log(pessoas);
}
```

```html
<label>Digite seu nome aqui</label>
<input type='text' id='nome' placeholder='aquii'>
<label>Digite sua idade aqui</label>
<input type='text' id='idade' placeholder='aquii'>
<button onclick='vai()'>
  Teste aqui
</button>
```

**Please Note:** You can also simply use the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) *property* of the array as the current *index* in which case you do need to maintain the variable:

```js
var pessoas = [];
function vai(){
  var pessoa = {
    nome: document.getElementById('nome').value,
    idade: document.getElementById('idade').value
  };
  pessoas[pessoas.length] = pessoa;
  console.log(pessoas);
}
```

```html
<label>Digite seu nome aqui</label>
<input type='text' id='nome' placeholder='aquii'>
<label>Digite sua idade aqui</label>
<input type='text' id='idade' placeholder='aquii'>
<button onclick='vai()'>
  Teste aqui
</button>
```

Comment: @aquasp, you are most welcome, you can refer the second answer in the updated answer if you do not want to use `push()`:)